# Need to disable "Save password?" popup while testing the page with selenide

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

When using selenide, how can I disable the Save Password popup in Chrome while testing? With the given code below, only the notifications popup was disabled but Chrome still asks if I want to save the password or not

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
Configuration.browser = "chrome";
Configuration.browserCapabilities = options;
```

Tried googling, but it only helped to remove the notifications popup